# A problem on synchronous generators

Tags: power, generator

This is part of a problem of my past examination in Electric Machines. I don't know how to solve it yet.

A salient pole synchronous generator \$ (X_q < X_d) \$ has a connected load at rated voltage. If the synchronous generator, operating with a voltage regulation zero, and a voltage drop in the resistance of armor 0.05pu (when the magnitude of the armature current is minimal), determine:
a) Power factor load.
b) The load angle \$ \delta \$ of the synchronous generator.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Optimal Cynic - the `homework` tag is deprecated

Comment: Too bad, it shouldn't be.  We get homework assignments occasionally, and this is a good way to let everyone know that.

Comment: @Olin - my decision to go into a question doesn't depend on it being homework or not, so I don't care about the tag. And upon reading it's often clear whether it's homework or not. Or, like in this question, OP says it is.

Comment: @stevenvh: I don't avoid homework questions, but I do answer them differently.  You don't want to just answer the question if it's homework.  Instead, you want to get the OP thinking about the theory so he can answer the question himself.  The homework tag is also useful for us to add to put the OP on notice that we know he's trying to get us to do his homework for him.

Comment: @Olin - I agree that we're not going to make others' homework, and that they at least show some effort. About the tag, maybe food for thought for meta?

Comment: @leo can you please fix this up a bit. what is a "voltage regulation zero"?

Comment: @CyberMen Voltage regulation zero means the terminal voltage does not vary at all under different loading conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The question has a flawed premise. If there is a non zero voltage drop across the armature resistance, then the generator cannot have zero voltage regulation, since the no load voltage at the terminals will exceed the full load voltage by the aforementioned voltage drop.